# events are not firing properly

Tags: asp.net

I am developing a web application in asp.net 4.0

In my application I am placing buttons inside the update panel. Inside the button click event I am calling the `AsynchRefresh` eventhandler of the chart control for continuous updating. After I click the button I want get the focus on this `AsyncRefresh` event, if I am using buttons with `UpdatePanel` the asyncRefresh event is not getting fired.

Without `UpdatePanel` the event `AsyncRefresh` event is getting fired, but I have to use the `UpdatePanel` otherwise the page will refresh.

Comment: you probably when you click it, you get a javascript error, that maybe have to do with the viewstate or something like that. Check the javascript error to see whats the issue.

Answer (score 0):

try calling the AsynchRefresh eventhandler of the chart control inside pageLoad event.

function pageLoad(sender, args) { 
    ... 
}

pageLoad is executed after every postback, synchronous or asynchronous. pageLoad is a reserved function name in ASP.NET AJAX that is for this purpose.

Reference : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386417.aspx